# Смена положения таблицы

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Допустим мы имеем таблицу в codeignaiter views/welcome_messege.php.Вот ее код:

```
<table id="node" border="1" class="table-bordered">
    <caption align="center"><h1><p class="text-primary">Список ссылок</p></h1></caption>
    <tr class="danger">
        <td>id</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>url</td>
        <td>status</td>
        <td>delete</td>
        <td>edit</td>
    </tr >
    <?php foreach($url_list as $val) : ?>
    <tr class="success">
    <td><?php echo  $val->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $val->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $val->url; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $val->status; ?></td>
    <td><button onClick="location.href='/welcome/delete/<?=$val->id?>';return false;">Delete‌​</button></td>
    <td><button>Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr class="info">
        <th></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="name1" size="10" maxlength="20"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="url1" size="10" maxlength="20"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="status1" size="10" maxlength="20"></th>
        <th><input type="submit" value="Add row"></th>

    </tr>

 </table>
```

Как сделать так что бы таблица находилась по центру вместе с ее заголовком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всегда помогает `margin:0 auto;` или `text-align:center;`

Хотя иногда нужно добавить позиционирование абсолютное или зависимое:
`position:absolute;` или `position:relative;`